# Is flow's information loss associated with structural subtyping inherent to this kind of polymorphism?

Tags: javascript, polymorphism, flowtype, subtyping, structural-typing

Structural subtyping in flow may lead to information loss:

```
type O = {x: number, y: number};
type P = {x: number, y: number, z: number}

function f(o: O) {
    return o.x * 2, o.y * 2, o;
}

const p: P = {x: 2, y: 3, z: 100};
const r = f(p);

r.z // type error (property not found)
```

(This code is terrible, because it performs visible mutations. It is for illustrative purposes only.)

I've read that row polymorphism is a concept to avoid this information loss without jeopardizing type safety.

Is there a way to achieve the same with subtype polymorphism?

**[EDIT]**

To address a greater audience I provide a brief explanation of the somewhat scary terminology:

- **Polymorpishm** is just a fancy word for determining if two types are equivalent, i.e. it makes a rigid type system more flexible
- **Parametric polymorphism** (generics in flow) states that two types are always equivalent, because types doesn't matter at all
- **Subtype polymorphism** (subtyping in flow) states that two types are equivalent if you can derive a hierarchy from them, i.e. subsume the subtype under its supertype
- **Row polymorphism** is similar to subtyping but solves the information loss issue (technically, however, there is no subtype relationship anymore, so it isn't a form of subtyping)
- **Bounded polymorphism** states that two types are equivalent for a specific purpose only, e.g. equality, order, mapping-over etc.

Answer (score 1):

For what I have read about Flowtype I am pretty sure that your function is the problem.

If you do this instead:

```
function f<T: O>(o: T): T {
  o.x *= 2;
  o.y *= 2;
  return o;
}

r.z; // okay
```

This works because of bounded polymorphism.  Now the body type checks under the assumption that T is a subtype of O. Furthermore, no information is lost across call sites.  [Read more about it here.](https://flow.org/blog/2015/03/12/Bounded-Polymorphism/)

Also, I hadn't heard of row polymorphism before, so I went and looked it up.  While looking it up I have read several things that seem to indicate that row polymorphism *isn't* subtyping. [1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53998/what-are-the-major-differences-between-row-polymorphism-and-subtyping), [2](https://brianmckenna.org/blog/row_polymorphism_isnt_subtyping), [3](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13047934).

To expand on this answer and to clarify why the OPs function doesn't work but the one that I proposed will work correctly.  T[his is a nice reference as well but is specific to Java](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/227918/java-use-polymorphism-or-bounded-type-parameters).

By having the function as:

```
function f(o: O) {
  return o.x * 2, o.y * 2, o;
}
```

The function specifies that it is explicitly looking for an object of type O, rather than an object of O or a subtype of O is allowed.  In the OPs function we are downcasting the parameter o to type O, rather than using a generic (this is bad).  The proper way to handle this is utilizing generics to specify that it can be type O or subtype of O, which can be done as follows:

```
function f<T: O> (o: T): T {
  o.x *= 2;
  o.y *= 2;
  return o;
}
```

[Check out the docs on how flow handles generics](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/) and how it is related to function parameters, object, etc..

The relevant part is:

- > "Generics allow you to hold onto the more specific type while adding a constraint. In this way types on generics act as “bounds”. [link](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#toc-generic-types-act-as-bounds)
- > "Generics sometimes allow you to pass types in like arguments to a function. These are known as parameterized generics (or parametric polymorphism)." [link](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#toc-parameterized-generics)

Comment: Why is my function the problem? It just relies on the promise of subtyping that one can pass in a subtype wherever its supertype is expected.  Your advice is to use bounded polymorphism instead. Well, this just means that subtyping is inferior to other forms of polymorphism - at least in certain cases and in the complexity it requires to implement a reliable algorithm.

Comment: @ftor I understand what you are saying, and it seems like it _should_ work, but with the function you have you're saying that it is explicitly looking for a param of type O, rather than a param of type O _or_ a subtype of O.  Specifying that the param is <T: O> you tell the compiler that you're expecting a param that will be type O or subtype O.  Check out how Java handles it https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/227918/java-use-polymorphism-or-bounded-type-parameters

Comment: @ftor Checkout my updated answer as it better explains my previous comment and OOP but in the context of flow.

Comment: +1 for your effort. I think the decisive clue is actually in one of your comments. This is subtyping. It is an OO concept and I am trying to judge it from a FP perspective. For me personally, this implicit downcasting seems like a bug in the subtyping portion of the type system. Well, you showed a more reliable alternative, which I'd call _bounded generics_ for structural typing. This kind of polymorphism makes much more sense to me than structural subtyping.

Comment: I agree that it seems a little odd in how it functions, and you could probably argue that it could be looked at as a bug.  The compiler should probably warn you when you are performing implicit downcasting, as I feel like the coding standards should encourage people not to do this.  Additionally, I feel like implicit downcasting can result in a lot of confusion when debugging as we've seen through your example.  I don't see a problem with the compiler just warning the user but still successfully compiling the program.